# how to combine multiple columns with grep and sum the values in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
Engine   General   Ladder.winch   engine.phe   subm.gear.box   aux.engine   pipeline.maintain    pipeline    pipe.line    engine.mpd
 1        12        22             2            4               2             4                    5            6             7
```

and so on with more than 10000 rows.

Now,I want to combine columns and add values to reduce the columns into broader categories. e.g `Engine,engine.phe,aux.engine,engine.mpd` should be combined into `Engine` category and all the values to be added. likewise `pipeline.maintain,pipeline,pipe.line` to be combined into `Pipeline` And rest columns to be added under `General` Category.

Desired dataframe would be

```
 Engine      Pipeline       General
   12          15             38
```

How can I do it in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option by extracting the concerned words from the `names` of the column, and using `tapply` to get the `sum`.  The `str_extract_all` returns a `list` ('lst').  Replace those elements which are having zero length with 'GENERAL', Then, using a group by function i.e. `tapply`, `unlist` the dataset, and use the grouping variables i.e replicated 'lst' and the `row` of 'df1' get the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
lst <- str_extract_all(toupper(sub("(pipe)\\.", "\\1", names(df1))),
          "ENGINE|PIPELINE|GENERAL")
lst[lengths(lst)==0] <- "GENERAL"
t(tapply(unlist(df1), list(unlist(lst)[col(df1)], row(df1)), FUN = sum))
#   ENGINE  GENERAL PIPELINE 
#1      12       38       15
```

Comment: When I run above code it gives me an error `Error in tapply(unlist(df[, c(71:105)]), unlist(lst), FUN = sum) : 
  arguments must have same length` I also have other text column along with this columns.

Comment: @Neil  The `lst` and `df[, 71:105]` are of different lengths.  Perhaps you need `names(df1)[71:105]` in the first line of code

Comment: I am passing following argument in `tapply`,`cnames <- tolower(colnames(df))  ||  cnames <- cnames[71:105]  ||   lst <- str_extract_all(toupper(sub("(pipe)\\.", "\\1", cnames)),
                       "ENGINE|PIPELINE|GENERAL")
lst[lengths(lst)==0] <- "GENERAL"
df <- tapply(unlist(df[,c(71:105)]), unlist(lst), FUN = sum)`

Comment: @Neil In the `cnames` you have 71:105 and later you are using `71:104` isn't the lengths different?

Comment: Sorry its a typo. `cnames is 71:105`

Comment: @ Yes the same error. `Error in tapply(unlist(df[, c(71:105)]), unlist(lst), FUN = sum) : 
  arguments must have same length`

Comment: @Neil Here, I assumed that there is only a single row as you showed in the example

Comment: @Neil I updated the post.  Could you try the edited one for `tapply`

Comment: Thanks a ton. its working now.can you please explain me the `tapply` statement which you used ?

Comment: @Neil Glad to help you.  Earlier, I misunderstood the question thought that there is only a single long row.  I added some description in the post

Answer (score 3):

Many ways in which you can do it, this is a more straight forward approach

```
# Example data.frame
dtf <- structure(list(Engine = c(1, 0, 1), 
   General = c(12, 3, 15), Ladder.winch = c(22, 28, 26), 
    engine.phe = c(2, 1, 0), subm.gear.box = c(4, 4, 10), 
    aux.engine = c(2, 3, 1), pipeline.maintain = c(4, 5, 1), 
    pipeline = c(5, 5, 2), pipe.line = c(6, 8, 2), engine.mpd = c(7, 8, 19)),
    .Names = c("Engine", "General", "Ladder.winch", "engine.phe", 
      "subm.gear.box", "aux.engine", "pipeline.maintain", 
      "pipeline", "pipe.line", "engine.mpd"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

with(dtf, data.frame(Engine=Engine+engine.phe+aux.engine+engine.mpd,
                   Pipeline=pipeline.maintain+pipeline+pipe.line,
                    General=General+Ladder.winch+subm.gear.box))

#   Engine Pipeline General
# 1     12       15      38
# 2     12       18      35
# 3     21        5      51

# a more generalized and 'greppy' solution
cnames <- tolower(colnames(dtf))
data.frame(Engine=rowSums(dtf[, grep("eng", cnames)]),
         Pipeline=rowSums(dtf[, grep("pip", cnames)]),
          General=rowSums(dtf[, !grepl("eng|pip", cnames)]))
```

Comment: I have `1100` such columns. I need more generalized approach like `grep` can we do that way?

Comment: I hope that's better. Of course the search words and how you define `general` depend on your need.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly better to store you data in long format. Therefore, my proposal would to approach your problem as below:

**1 - get your data in long format**

```
library(reshape2)
dfl <- melt(df)
```

**2 - create 'engine' and 'pipeline'-vectors**

```
e_vec <- c("Engine","engine.phe","aux.engine","engine.mpd")
p_vec <- c("pipeline.maintain","pipeline","pipe.line")
```

**3 - create a category column**

```
dfl$newcat <- c("general","engine","pipeline")[1 + dfl$variable %in% e_vec + 2*(dfl$variable %in% p_vec)]
```

The result:

```
> dfl
            variable value   newcat
1             Engine     1   engine
2            General    12  general
3       Ladder.winch    22  general
4         engine.phe     2   engine
5      subm.gear.box     4  general
6         aux.engine     2   engine
7  pipeline.maintain     4 pipeline
8           pipeline     5 pipeline
9          pipe.line     6 pipeline
10        engine.mpd     7   engine
```

Now you can use `aggregate` to get the final result:

```
> aggregate(value ~ newcat, dfl, sum)
    newcat value
1   engine    12
2  general    38
3 pipeline    15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myfactors = ifelse(grepl("engine", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE), "Engine",
                   ifelse(grepl("pipe|pipeline", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE), "Pipeline",
                          "General"))
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, myfactors), rowSums))
#  Engine General Pipeline
#1     12      38       15
#2     12      35       18
#3     21      51        5
```

`df` is the data from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512089/7128934)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer. Kudos!!